# Probability question where an object is chosen randomly out of two objects

Tags: probability

I am stuck at the following probability problem. Will appreciate your help.

**Two opera singers, Mario and Clarissa both perform on the same night, in separate recitals. The independent probabilities that two newspapers X and Y publish reviews of their recitals are given below:**

## Probability of review in newspaper X

**Mario's recital - 1/2, 
Clarissa's recital - 2/3**

## Probability of review in newspaper Y

**Mario's recital - 1/4,
Clarissa's recital - 2/5**

**Mario buys one of the newspapers at random. What is the probability that it has reviewed "both" recitals?**

I did this way: **P(reviewed both recitals) = P(buys paper X)*P(X reviews Mario)*P(X reviews Clarissa) = (1/2)(1/2)(2/3) = 1/6**

But 1/6 is not the correct answer. Let me know where I am wrong and why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened to the "Mario buys $Y$" case?

Comment: Note:  you implicitly assume that, for a given paper, the two reviews are independent events.  That is unlikely...surely papers make decisions about one report based on the inclusion/exclusion of others.  You don't have any information regarding the dependence, but whatever assumption you make should be explicit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should not it be:

\begin{align*}
P(\text{reviewed both recitals})& = P(\text{buys paper $X$})\times P(\text{$X$ reviews both Mario & Clarissa}) \\
&\qquad+ P(\text{buys paper $Y$})\times P(\text{$Y$ reviews both Mario & Clarissa}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{5} \\
&= \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{20} = \frac{13}{60}
\end{align*}
(assuming independence of the appearance of the reviews)

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_x$ be the event "Mario buyed paper $X$", and let $B_x^c$ denote the complementary event . Let $R$ be the event "the buyed paper reviewed both recitals"

Then $P(R)= P(R \cap B_x)+P(R \cap B_x^c)=P(R\mid B_x)P(B_x)+P(R\mid B_x^c)P(B_x^c)$

Now, $P(B_x)=P(B_x^c)=\frac{1}{2}$. And $P(R\mid B_x)= \frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{3}$ ... Surely you can go on from here.